# How do i fix this RemoteDataError, in Pandas DataReader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

i want to download FTSE historical data but i cant download it, i have reinstalled pandas_datareader but the problem still persisted

there are no issues downloading other tickers such as S&P, Dow Jones ,etc only FTSE

this is the following code i used:

```py
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from pandas_datareader import data as wb

FTSE = wb.DataReader('^FTSE', data_source='yahoo', start='1990-1-1')
```

i get the following error message when i perform the above code and same error occurs in Anaconda3

> > Blockquote
>
> "
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 FTSE = wb.DataReader('^FTSE', data_source='yahoo', start='2000-1-1')
>
> C:\Users****\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.pyc
>   in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause,
>   session, access_key)
>       308                                 adjust_price=False, chunksize=25,
>       309                                 retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause,
>   --> 310                                 session=session).read()
>       311 
>       312     elif data_source == "google":
>
> C:\Users****\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.pyc
>   in read(self)
>       208         if isinstance(self.symbols, (compat.string_types, int)):
>       209             df = self._read_one_data(self.url,
>   --> 210                                      params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
>       211         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
>       212         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):
>
> C:\Users****\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.pyc
>   in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
>       134         except KeyError:
>       135             msg = 'No data fetched for symbol {} using {}'
>   --> 136             raise RemoteDataError(msg.format(symbol, self.**class**.**name**))
>       137 
>       138         # price data
>
> RemoteDataError: No data fetched for symbol ^FTSE using
>   YahooDailyReader "

Comment: Have you confirmed there is data available to download? Why is there a hat symbol at the beginning of the string `^FTSE` ?  Also, the date on your sample code is different from the error message..

Comment: yes there is data available for download, and '^FTSE' has hat symbol because its what yahoo finance recognizes as FTSE 100, like S&P 500 has (^GSPC) which works for s&p 500, and there are different dates because i tried different dates for the code hoping it was an date issue but the problem still persisted

Comment: it's been a year, so still no workable solution right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ^ character:

```
FTSE = wb.DataReader('\^FTSE', data_source='yahoo', start='1990-1-1')
```

Though I'm unsure why this only seems to be an issue for ^STI and ^FTSE, but  not ^GSPC, ^FCHI, ^RUT or any other indices, so I can't give an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I also got the same error while accessing the sti, index for the Singaporean benchmark. The index should be called as ^STI using yahoo finance. I have attached a link here about using the alphavantage API.
https://rapidapi.com/blog/stock-market-prediction-python-api/